Angular HttpClient is calling the GET request twice
I'm facing an issue where Angular's HttpClient is making a GET request twice, but only one request is visible in the browser's network tab. However, my backend logs show that the GET request is being triggered twice.
What I've Tried
I checked the Network tab in the browser's developer tools, and it shows only one request being fired.
On the backend (Spring Boot Reactive), I'm logging every incoming request, and I see the request being logged twice.
I added a console.log in Angular before the request is made, and it only logs the URL once.
I'm using Angular's HttpClient with a simple GET request that fetches data from the backend. The relevant code is below.

**This is my Api Service.**

export class StudentApiService {
  public cachedStudent$: Observable<StudentDto>;export class StudentApiService {

  public cachedStudent$: Observable<StudentDto>;
    
getStudent(id: string, withParentInfo: boolean): Observable<StudentDto> {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer your-token',  // Example of adding a token
    'Custom-Header': 'custom-value'
  });
  const url = `${this.base_url}/by-id/${id}?withParentInfo=${withParentInfo}`;
  if (!this.cachedStudent$) {
    this.cachedStudent$=this.http.get<StudentDto>(url, { headers }).pipe(
      take(1),
      retry(1),
      shareReplay(1)
    )
  }
  return this.cachedStudent$;
} 
}

**This is my Component Class**

export class AddEditStudentComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy {

constructor(private studentApi: StudentApiService,
           private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {}


  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngOnInit called');
    const url = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.url[0].path;
this.studentId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('studentId');
      // Subscribe to the Subject's observable
      this.sub.add(
        this.studentApi.getStudent(this.studentId, false).subscribe({
          next: data => {
        console.log(data);
          },
          error: err => {
            console.log('Error fetching student data:', err);
          }
        })
      );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }

}


What I've Investigated
Caching: I have used shareReplay(1) to prevent multiple requests, but the issue persists.
Route Changes: I've checked to see if the route reinitialization could be causing the request to fire twice, but I don't see any route-related issues.
ngOnInit: The ngOnInit() method in my component is only triggered once, so it doesn't seem like the component is being reloaded unnecessarily.

If the network tab shows just one request, it is just one request. Maybe the server side logging is faulty? Try to do the request in Postman, and check if this request is also logged twice.

Thank you for the suggestion! @JSONDerulo I already tried making the request using Postman, and in that case, the backend only logs one request. This confirms that the issue occurs specifically when the request is made from Angular.

Can you see the request type of both request, one could be of type OPTIONS, still even that should show up in networks tab unless filtered out.

Thank you for the reply @Shub You are right, I can see two req in network tab one is PREFLIGHT and One is xhr . How to solve this please .

There will always be a preflight request with ajax. You can't prevent the browser from making this call.

Thank you for reply @BrandonTaylor but my backend log showing 2 query . Is it ok to query database twice ? .

preflight requests shouldn't be triggering code in your API. They're just test requests to see if a method is safe to call.

only cross-site requests would trigger a pre-flight call by the browser.  This might happen when debugging locally using two different ports on localhost.  (those are treated as two different domains)  Once you publish that should go away as long as everything is kept same-site/domain.  It is sort of strange you aren't seeing a CORS error in the browser, though.

Two reason maybe:
1- Probably you have ssr enabled setting and you are trying to call http request with jwt token and there is no jwt token in server and server reponse with 401 status. so in client you call the http request again because of error in the server.
2- your web server config did that.
